# Different fill methods for different columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reindexing a dataframe in the standard way, i.e.

```
df.reindex(newIndex,method='ffill')
```

But realized I need to handle missing data differently on a column-by-column basis. That is, for some columns I want to ffill, but for others I want to missing values recorded as NAs.

For simplicity, let's say I have column X that I want ffilled, and column Y that I want NA-filled. How can I call .reindex to accomplish this?

Comment: Can't you call it twice? With `columns=[Y]` argument and `columns=[X]` argument?

Comment: @jaor So you mean doing two separate indexes, and then merging the two resulting dataframes?

Comment: I guess. Parameter `columns` affect only specified columns. It's all in here I guess http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex

Comment: ``reindex``, then ``fillna`` on individual columns as needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `reindex()` first, and then call `ffill()` for columns:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[10, 20, 30], "B":[100, 200, 300], 
                   "C":[100, 200, 300]}, index=[2, 6, 8])
df2 = df.reindex([2,4,6,8,10])

for col in ["A", "B"]:
    df2[col].ffill(inplace=True)
print df2
```

output:

```
    A    B    C
2   10  100  100
4   10  100  NaN
6   20  200  200
8   30  300  300
10  30  300  NaN
```